# Python - Concatenate an item from a list with an item from another list

Tags: python, list

I need to concatenate an item from a list with an item from another list. In my case the item is a string (a path more exactly). After the concatenation I want to obtain a list with all the possible items resulted from concatenation.

Example:

```
list1 = ['Library/FolderA/', 'Library/FolderB/', 'Library/FolderC/']

list2 = ['FileA', 'FileB']
```

I want to obtain a list like this:

```
[
    'Library/FolderA/FileA', 
    'Library/FolderA/FileB', 
    'Library/FolderB/FileA', 
    'Library/FolderB/FileB', 
    'Library/FolderC/FileA', 
    'Library/FolderC/FileB'
]
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

```
In [11]: [d+f for (d,f) in itertools.product(list1, list2)]
Out[11]: 
['Library/FolderA/FileA',
 'Library/FolderA/FileB',
 'Library/FolderB/FileA',
 'Library/FolderB/FileB',
 'Library/FolderC/FileA',
 'Library/FolderC/FileB']
```

or, slightly more portably (and perhaps robustly):

```
In [16]: [os.path.join(*p) for p in itertools.product(list1, list2)]
Out[16]: 
['Library/FolderA/FileA',
 'Library/FolderA/FileB',
 'Library/FolderB/FileA',
 'Library/FolderB/FileB',
 'Library/FolderC/FileA',
 'Library/FolderC/FileB']
```

Comment: It might be better to use `os.path.join()` here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
>>> [d + f for d in list1 for f in list2]
['Library/FolderA/FileA', 'Library/FolderA/FileB', 'Library/FolderB/FileA', 'Library/FolderB/FileB', 'Library/FolderC/FileA', 'Library/FolderC/FileB']
```

You may want to use `os.path.join()` instead of simple concatenation though.

Answer (score 0):

The built-in [`itertools`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) module defines a `product()` function for this:

```
import itertools
result = itertools.product(list1, list2)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `for` loop can do this easily:

```
my_list, combo = [], ''
list1 = ['Library/FolderA/', 'Library/FolderB/', 'Library/FolderC/']
list2 = ['FileA', 'FileB']
for x in list1:
   for y in list2:
      combo = x + y
      my_list.append(combo)
return my_list
```

You can also just print them:

```
list1 = ['Library/FolderA/', 'Library/FolderB/', 'Library/FolderC/']
list2 = ['FileA', 'FileB']
for x in list1:
   for y in list2:
      print str(x + y)
```